# How to define inputs in a `push` trigger in Github Actions?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I want to have input variables defined in the inputs section of the `push` event.

I get this error via my ID:

```
Property inputs is not allowed.yaml-schema: GitHub Workflow
```

And the variable is not passed along to the jobs, just an empty string is placed.

The other alternative I think is to use env variables but wanted to know if there is a way to have input with default values in the `push` event.

Snippet of my workflow file:

```
name: Main

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - <other branch>
    inputs:
      database_version:
        type: string
        required: true
        default: abcd
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the doc about [Metadata syntax for Github Action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions).

As you can see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore) there is no `inputs` property for `on.push`. Why you want to pass a parameter to the `on.push`? That property is to allow an action run on specific `branch` or `tag`.

That property exist for:

- [on.workflow_call.inputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_callinputs)
- [on.workflow_dispatch.inputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatchinputs)

Comment: How can I define workflow level variables that can be used in a job that uses `with`? Basically this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76211635/how-to-use-env-variables-in-the-with-block-of-github-action-workflows

Comment: Here you have a doc for [variables in workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables). Instead of showing what you are trying to do at level configuration, provide details of what you want to do at high level. Do you want to create a custom action? Do you want to define a workflow for your repo? Where that variable should come from? Just a value set in the same file? As setting of the repo? In a specific environment?

Comment: "Why you want to pass a parameter to the on.push?" to be able to test a github action rapidly on every push and make sure that it's handling the inputs correctly

Comment: when you say "**test a github action**", are you talking about [manually run a github action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/manually-running-a-workflow)? If that the case, you have [on.workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatch) that let's you setup the action to be triggered from the `actions` in the github web of your repo as it is detailed in the docs. Then you can setup all the inputs with default values you want

Comment: github actions with on.workflow_dispatch can only be triggered on the main branch. So when you're in a development phase, it's quite difficult to test your inputs

Comment: This is not correct: "github actions with on.workflow_dispatch can only be triggered on the main branch." The only problem is, if a workflow file exists on a feature branch but not on the main branch, it is not listed in Actions page, hence cannot be triggered. If they do exist in both branches, then you can run workflows from other branches.