# How to use env variables in the `with` block of Github Action workflows?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, cicd

I want to define a key-value pair for the entire workflow and access it in the `with` block of multiple jobs.

Right now, I get the error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yaml (Line: 41, Col: 25): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.database_version .github/workflows/main.yaml (Line: 64, Col: 25): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.database_version
```

My snippet is as follows:

```
name: Main

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - fix-main-deployment-workflow-post-database_version

env:
  database_version: 3.1.0-git-c919c26

jobs:

  <job_name>:
    name: Deploy to <some zone>
    needs:
      - helm
      - docker
    uses: <another yaml>
    with:
      database_version: ${{ env.database_version }}
```

I also tried removing the `env` and directly referencing it:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yaml (Line: 41, Col: 25): Unrecognized named-value: 'database_version'. Located at position 1 within expression: database_version .github/workflows/main.yaml (Line: 64, Col: 25): Unrecognized named-value: 'database_version'. Located at position 1 within expression: database_version
```

Comment: There is not `steps` field in the `<job_name>` implementation you shared. Is it informed on the original workflow?

Comment: Yes, the workflow referred in the `uses` section has the steps in many jobs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing env variable inputs to a reusable workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73305126/passing-env-variable-inputs-to-a-reusable-workflow)

Comment: For reusable workflows, you can configure a separate job to set env vars as output parameters and then use those in the input parameters. See the duplicate threads for an example.

Answer (score 0):

It is [limitation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#limitations) of reusable workflows. Environments specified **inside** YAML are worthless as they aren't passed down to nested YAMLs.

To achieve what you want you can:

1. use [vars](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context) context instead or...
2. wrap your workflow into another [reusable flow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#creating-a-reusable-workflow) with default input

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      database_version:
        default: '3.1.0-git-c919c26'
        type: string

jobs:
  nested-job:
    name: Deploy to <some zone>
    needs:
      - helm
      - docker
    uses: <another yaml>
    with:
      database_version: ${{ inputs.database_version }}
```

And then you call your workflow like this:

```
name: Main

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - fix-main-deployment-workflow-post-database_version

jobs:
  <job_name>:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/<workflow_above_name>.yml
# optionally you can inherit secrets
    secrets: inherit
# and add some fixed inputs
    with:
      some_input: 'some_fixed_value'
```